# keras, LSTM - predict on inputs of different length?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have fitted an LSTM that deals with inputs of different length:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=10, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(None, 5)))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Having fitted the model, I want to test it on inputs of different size.

```
x_test.shape # = 100000
x_test[0].shape # = (1, 5)
x_test[1].shape # = (3, 5)
x_test[2].shape # = (8, 5)
```

Testing on single instances `j` is not a problem (`model.predict(x_test[j]`), but looping on all of them is **really slow**.

Is there a way of speeding up the computation? `model.predict(x_test)` does not work. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I have found so far is grouping together data windows with the same length. For my problem, it's enough to significantly speed up the computation.

Hope this trick would help other people.

```py
import numpy as np

def predict_custom(model, x):
    """x should be a list of np.arrays with different number of rows, but same number of columns"""
    
    # dictionary with key = length of the window, value = indices of samples with such length
    dic = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(x):
        if dic.get(x.shape[0]):
            dic[x.shape[0]].append(i)
        else:
            dic[x.shape[0]] = [i]
    
    y_pred = np.full((len(x),1), np.nan)
    
    # loop over dictionary and predict together samples of the same length
    for key, indexes in dic.items():
        # select samples of the same length (conversion to np.array is used for subsetting "x" using "indexes")
        x = np.asarray(x, dtype=object)[indexes].tolist()
        # gather such samples in a 3D np.array
        x_3d = np.stack(x, axis=0)
        # use dictionary values to insert results in the correspondent row of y_pred
        y_pred[indexes] = model.predict(x_3d)
        
    return y_pred
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to speed up model inference is to **run inference on GPU**, instead of the CPU (I'm assuming you are not already doing that). You can set up GPU support by following the official guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu). Unless you are explicitly asking keras to run inference on CPU, your code should work as is, without any changes. To confirm if you are using GPU, you can use [this](https://kegui.medium.com/how-do-i-know-i-am-running-keras-model-on-gpu-a9cdcc24f986) article.

Hope the answer was helpful!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, the issue is not that model.predict is slow, but that the for loop is slow! Indeed, model.predict is quite fast if all the data points have the same size. In my case, however this does not happen and I have to loop over each window to obatin predictions. I was asking if there is a fast way to predict on an array of data of different length. The best solution that I have found so far is grouping together data windows with the same length.

Comment: Hmm I see. I would still recommend you try to run your model's inferences on GPU. Even a relatively minor time saving over a single inference can add up to a significant value over a larger number of inferences. If you want to run inference on CPU anyway, you can try multi-processing. Run a model for every core of your CPU and collect the results.